# Surveys and Answers, relation on many-to-many

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have the following database scheme (I don't know if it's perfect but I think it's allright?)

[image]

> It's a system where a User has many Surveys, the Users provide Answers for Questions in the Survey_Answers table.

Now a User can have multiple Surveys, it's the same questions but in a later time of the year they have to fill in the survey again.

I'm nearly there, I'm just wondering how to connect the answers to the survey. Should I make a relation between survey_answers and user_surveys.. thus adding an id to the user_surveys table

Or do you think it's ok to make a relation to the surveys table? I'm not sure which one is correct.

I outlined the 2 possibilities in the second screenshot.

[image]

Looking forward to your responses! 
Thank you.

Comment: [_Optimal schema for many:many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: don't see how it can help me? Care to elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably depends on how your system is most likely/most frequently going to navigate the relationship.

If you are more likely to be looking at a Users answers and saying - hey let me see when this question was answered, as part of which dated survey, then you should join on user_surveys (I am assuming that the employee_id you are storing would match the user_id in user_surveys)

If you're more likely to be looking at a Users answers and saying - hey what survey did this question belong to, then you should join on Surveys.

You can still answer either question whichever join you use, it will just be a matter of more optimal performance (fewer table joins when trying to answer the most common query).

In reality there probably isn't much in it, so you could always toss a coin  :)

Comment: Great answer thank you very much! Is the db scheme somewhat okay? I'm always uncertain if I'm choosing the correct way to go with all this

Comment: Oh and would it be a good idea to add journey_id to the users table? For example upon creating a new User. I need to make sure the existing steps of the chosen journey he will follow, will be added to the user_steps. In that wat I know what user has what journey, right?

Comment: That would depend if a user can have many journeys and many users can follow the same journey then you need a many-many table between users and journeys, just holding user_id and journey_id (perhaps with an active flag added to show which journey the user is currently on).  Schema looks ok but of course impossible to say without understanding all the use cases.